# Is there any point to equipping a bracelet that doesn't match your sword?

Tags: crystalis

For Crystalis on the NES, is there a point to equipping a bracelet that doesn't match the sword you are holding?

Answer (score 6):

Equipping a Bracelet of a different sword should let you charge your current sword to Level 2 maximum. This is as opposed to equipping nothing at all, which restricts you to Level 1 charging. The main utility of doing this is to comfortably hold a Level 2 charge instead of needing to constantly walk around to avoid building up to a Level 3 charge (and thus conserve your MP).

In case it needed the clarification, this does not provide access to a Level 2 charge which you did not already have access to. It's merely a method to restrict yourself once you have the bracelet that does match your sword.

Comment: In the version i am playing (i heard some nes games have different builds) i can only charge up to lvl 1. Which isnt convenient. I was hoping there was some combo i could do to kill every enemy in an area instead of switching a lot but it looks like that isnt possible either

Comment: @acid That could entirely be the case. I could also be mistaken on it being the bracelet, but I distinctly remember that there was some ability to fix charge up to level 2. Regardless, what I definitely know is that there is no method to avoid having to switch swords for different enemies.

Comment: Ugh, I don't have a Crystalis saved game in either version (NES or GBC) so I can't check. :/